# How to get the name of an ID from other table [LARAVEL]

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-7

This query that I did is to fetch `service_id` and its count in `ServiceOrder` model:

```
$test =  DB::table('serviceorders')
      ->select('serviceorders.service_id', DB::raw('COUNT(services.id) AS count'))
      ->join('services', 'serviceorders.service_id', '=', 'services.id')
      ->groupBy('serviceorders.service_id')
      ->whereMonth('serviceorders.created_at',Carbon::now("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")->month)
      ->get();
```

I have no idea how to fetch the name of an id since it is at another model

Here's the result when I `dd($test)`

[image]

as you can see, it displays `service_id` because yeah I typed that but I don't know how to fetch the `serviceName` . also this way of query can be difficult if I'm trying to display it in a pie chart using chartJs (correct me if it is easy)

these are the tables involved

[image]

I am also looking for a right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go using Eloquent functions:

```php
ServiceOrder::withCount('services')
            ->whereMonth('created_at', today()->month)
            ->having('services_count', '>', 0) // this is optional if you wish to avoid orders with 0 services
            ->get();
// now you will have this attribute `services_count`

// NOTE: Adjust your Carbon timezone within your `config/app.php` timezone to be 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
```

It might not work if you don't have a relation (function) called services() within your ServiceOrder model, and for sure I guessed that this is your model name :) let me know if it was different so I can help out.

Comment: may i know what is it withCount('services') . what if i wanna count the service_id from serviceorders. it didnt work when i put service_id, i did create relationship in serviceorder model which is serv() that calls service model

Comment: In this case change it to `withCount('serv')` and this means the attribute is now called `serv_count` it will do the count for you. and Please don't name your relations in such manner, I mean "serv" is not readable at all